# what is the python project structure

Tags: python, structure, project

i need to know what i should put in a new python project directories,
such as **/core**, **/lib**... and what they must contain & what are the other important things todo

i have browsed some articles about python project structure but got nothing useful. http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/

```
/core/ -> what should contain as an example?
....
```

need some help with that, and thanks in advance

Comment: This is probably too broad a question. Unless you're building for a specific API, there's no hard and fast rules for this.

Comment: this completely depends on the project.  If you provide some details on what you intend to do we may be of some help but there isn't much to offer otherwise because, as @ColinBasnett said, "there's no hard and fast rules for this."

Comment: @PatrickSchaefer im working on a python project that handle network connections, post, get than retreive data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is advice for someone who is starting completely afresh, as I imagine you do based on your question.

There are generally no `core` or `lib` directories in a python project. Start your project in one file. Run it with `python`. Once your file gets too big, start separating things into other files, and after that into modules (subdirectories with `__init__.py` files).

Somewhere during that process, read the [link](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/) you have also included several times, try and understand it, because that contains very good advice on what you need to know about structure.